# ROS message_filters sync random-sized topics with roscpp

Tags: c++, ros

I knew it's possible to sync multiple topics by passing array as callback function's argument with rospy as below:

```py
robots_num = 4
_subscribers = []
for i in range(0, robots_num):
    _sub_obs = message_filters.Subscriber("/robot{}/odom".format(str(i)), Odometry)
    _subscribers.append(_sub_obs)

ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(_subscribers, 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
ts.registerCallback(self.__callback)

def __callback(self, *data):
    """
    callback value:
    data[0]: robot0's odom
    data[1]: robot1's odom
    data[2]: robot2's odom
    ...
    """
    # do something
    pass
```

Is it possible deal with unsized multiple topics with roscpp?
Because I hope I can easily sync multiple topics that I want.

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "unsized multiple topics"? Message filters are available and documented for C++ here: http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Sorry for uncleared experession. Because I hope I can sync different topics at different times, maybe sync 4 robots' odom this time and sync 12 robots' odom next time. And I also want to sync different type of topic.
So, I'm looking for the flexible solution with C++, like passing subscribers as callback's argument in Python.